# What should I return from Controller if there is no records in database, and I want to indicate this fact to the user?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to auto-fill textbox if member id exists in database. Otherwise I want to disaplay "please enter correct Member-Id"

**Here is my Jquery Code:**

```
$('#memberid').focusout(function () {             
     $.getJSON('/ContactUs/GetMember/' + $('#memberid').val(), function (data) {
         $('#FName').val(data[0].M_Fname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
         $('#LName').val(data[0].M_Lname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
         $('#Email_Id').val(data[0].M_Emailid).attr("readonly", "readonly");
         $('#Cno').val(data[0].M_ContactNo).attr("readonly", "readonly");
         //alert(data);
         //alert(data[0].M_Fname);
     });
})
```

**And here is my Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetMember(string id)
{
   int id1 =Convert.ToInt32(id);
   clubDataContext db = new clubDataContext();
   var result = from r in db.M_Registarions
                where r.M_id == (id1)
                select new { r.M_Fname, r.M_Lname, r.M_Emailid, r.M_ContactNo };
   if (result.Any())
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   else
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here I am returning JsonResult and using getJSON to get data from database.

Comment: You could create a wrapper object containing the `result` and the `message` you wish to display.

Comment: reworded title so it makes sense, thanks to @AndreiV for indicating what the OP was on about! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the controller action does exactly what it should.. return nothing if nothing is found. Just check for an empty response on the client side..

```
$('#memberid').focusout(function () {             
     $.getJSON('/ContactUs/GetMember/' + $('#memberid').val(), function (data) {
         if(data.length > 0){
             $('#FName').val(data[0].M_Fname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
             $('#LName').val(data[0].M_Lname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
             $('#Email_Id').val(data[0].M_Emailid).attr("readonly", "readonly");
             $('#Cno').val(data[0].M_ContactNo).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        }else{
            //NOTHING WAS FOUND
        }
     });
})
```

Alternatively you can return an Http 404 (Not Found) and handle the error...

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetMember(string id)
{
   int id1 =Convert.ToInt32(id);
   clubDataContext db = new clubDataContext();
   var result = from r in db.M_Registarions
                where r.M_id == (id1)
                select new { r.M_Fname, r.M_Lname, r.M_Emailid, r.M_ContactNo };
   if (result.Any())
       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   else
       return HttpNotFound();
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#memberid').focusout(function () {             
     $.getJSON('/ContactUs/GetMember/' + $('#memberid').val(), function (data) {
             $('#FName').val(data[0].M_Fname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
             $('#LName').val(data[0].M_Lname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
             $('#Email_Id').val(data[0].M_Emailid).attr("readonly", "readonly");
             $('#Cno').val(data[0].M_ContactNo).attr("readonly", "readonly");           
     }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if(jqXHR.status == 404){
            //NOTFOUND
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ContactUs/GetMember/',
    data: {id: $('#memberid').val()},
    success: function(data){
        //check if any results returned
        if(data.result.length > 0){
            $('#FName').val(data[0].M_Fname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
            $('#LName').val(data[0].M_Lname).attr("readonly", "readonly");
            $('#Email_Id').val(data[0].M_Emailid).attr("readonly", "readonly");
            $('#Cno').val(data[0].M_ContactNo).attr("readonly", "readonly");
        }else{
            //send message to user if results are 0
            alert('no results were returned');
        }
    }
})
```